# “position absolute” styled elements scroll over top of "stay-on-top menu"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I realise that this gets said on numerous occasions but – I am very new to any form of web development and I have been playing around trying to incorporate various pieces of code into one another to aid my knowledge. I coded a home page and on it I had an image, Parola-Icon.png and two blocks of text that I positioned by using this style of code

```
<img style="position:absolute; top:570px; left:217px; width:183px; height:213px" src="http://www.pedroduino.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Hardware-Parola-Icon.png">
```

I then combined the content of the page that I developed into a piece of stay-on-top menu code that I found here

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/create-stay-on-top-menu-css3-jquery/

The menu section obviously works  flawlessly but the problem is that when I scroll down the page the three “position absolute” styled elements slide up over the top rather than behind the menu. I did try changing the value of the position property, to no avail. Keeping in mind that my skilset, is suffice to say minimal, might anyone be able to help me to identify and rectify this problem. The three files for this page are not on a live site but I have posted them on Github here.

https://gist.github.com/Pedro147/f8c4f78c0b51f9a8717f

They are named

- index_1.html
- style_1.css
- nagging-menu.js

If anyone might be able to take the time to have a look I would be really appreciative.
I hope that I have explained myself adequately 
thanks Pedro.

Comment: Did you try adding a `z-index` on the menu higher then on your three "position absolute" elements? More about the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property.

Comment: Thank you so much Ex-iT. That fixed it no problemo :-) It is easy when you know how isn't it. I just set the z-index of the menu item in the style sheet to 5 and the problem disappeared and also the offending "position absolute" elements disappeared "under the menu". Sorry about my vagueness in regard to the correct terminology but I will pick it up as I go. Thanks again and have a great day, Pedro.